# Probability of getting certain numbers at least once in four dice rolls

Tags: probability

Let us suppose we have normal dice and we   rolled it 4 times,there is two question which we  are asked

1. probability that at least one of number is less then $4$

we answered it  light this : probability that neither of them is  less then $4$ is $1/81$

so answer to this question will be   $1-1/81=80/81$

2.at least one of them is $6$,

this  should equal  probability that  one of them is $6$ +probability that two of them is equal $6$ +probability that three of them is $6$+probability that all of them is $6$  are we  right?

thanks in advance

Comment: In 2 you could proceed with 1-P(none are 6). This is similar to what you did in one.

Comment: Your English needs some improvement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For (1), probability that none is less than $4$ is $\left(\frac12\right)^4=\frac{1}{16}$.  So probability at least one is less than $4$ is $\frac{15}{16}$.

(2) Is easier as $1-P(\mbox{no sixes)})=1-\left(\frac56\right)^4$

Comment: sorry i wrote  incorrectly

Comment: for first one i mixed  this situation with one  situation which i have not  posted and that why, definitely  you are right